# How to find minimum value of : $\frac{7x^2 - 2xy + 3y^2}{x^2 - y^2}$?

Tags: functions

How to find minimum value of $\dfrac{7x^2 - 2xy + 3y^2}{x^2 - y^2}$ for two positive numbers $x$ and $y$ such that $x > y$?

I'm seeing this type of problem for the first time. My teacher gave this question and asked to solve it.

I tried to substitute $x = \sin\theta$ and $y = \cos\theta$ but that is not working.

Can anyone give me some hint how do solve it? I don't think that the concept of maxima and minima using derivative would either work.

Comment: Hint: set $y=tx$ so that $0<t<1$; then the problem reduces to minimizing a function of the single variable $t$.

Comment: @GregMartin is it allowed to do manipulation with the variable?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "allowed". For any two positive numbers $x>y$, there exists $t\in(0,1)$ such that $y=tx$ (indeed $t=\frac yx$), and vice versa. So all the values of the function are the same with both the new variables and the old variables, and we're trying to understand the values.

Comment: Surely one is "allowed" to substitute $y=tx$ just as much as you substituted $x = \sin \theta$ and $y = \cos \theta$.  Indeed the substitution Greg Martin proposes is based on the problem conditions that $x \gt y$ and both $x,y$ are positive (something your attempt would not ensure).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had the right-ish idea with your substitution, however you only found values on the unit circle. In a slightly easier form, consider the substitution

$$\begin{cases}x = r\cosh \tau \\ y = r\sinh\tau 
\end{cases} \implies f(\tau) = 7\cosh^2\tau-\sinh 2\tau+3\sinh^2\tau$$

where the $r$'s cancel. Then

$$f'(\tau) = 7\sinh 2\tau - 2 \cosh 2\tau+3 \sinh 2\tau = 0 \implies \tanh 2\tau = \frac{1}{5}$$

This makes an easier back substitution with the original function in terms of $2\tau$'s

$$f(\tau) = 5\cosh 2\tau - \sinh 2\tau + 2 $$

Then use $\tanh^2z + \operatorname{sech}^2z = 1$ to obtain

$$\begin{cases}\cosh 2\tau = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{5}^2}} = \frac{5}{\sqrt{24}} \\ \sinh 2\tau = \frac{1}{\sqrt{24}}\end{cases} \implies f(\tau) \geq \sqrt{24} + 2$$

Comment: Thanks for answering. I don't know about hyperbolic functions. Is there any other way of doing so?

Comment: @Anonymous Personally I don't understand the argument "don't know hyperbolics" - they aren't that much different from trig and if you know one it takes 10 minutes to learn the other. However, you have the other option from Greg Martin to set $y=tx$ and differentiate. Alternatively, given the way the answer looks note that $$f(x,y) = \frac{5x^2-2xy+5y^2}{x^2-y^2}+2$$ which is slightly more symmetric, so maybe there is a trick to show that $$\frac{5x^2-2xy+5y^2}{x^2-y^2} \geq \sqrt{24}$$

Comment: i don't know why the manipulation with the variable is allowed? Is it?

Comment: This is allowed as $x$ and $y$ are numbers and not functions (so $y$ does not have to be a function of $x$ for this to work). Alternatively, divide top and bottom by $x^2$ and then you have a function in $y/x$.